# Cannot read properties of an object

Tags: javascript

I have spent many hours on this irritating problem in my code. I define a class to hold several properties. I then populate those properties into a 2d array. From there, I then attempt to modify random elements in the 2d array. I keep getting the message

`"Cannot read property of 'attribute' of undefined"`

where attribute is any one of the three attributes in my object. Here is my code:

```js
var table = new Array();
var adjacencyList = new Array();

var cell = function (prop) {
 var atrbs = {
  x: prop.x,
  y: prop.y,
  isVisited: prop.isVisited
 }
 return atrbs;
};

var createTable = function(size){
 for(var row = 0; row < size; row++){
  table[row] = new Array();
  for(var column = 0; column < size; column++){
   table[row][column] = new cell({x: row, y: column, isVisited: false});
  }
 }
};

function print(){
 for(var row = 0; row < table.length; row++){
  for(var column = 0; column < table[row].length; column++){
   console.log(table[row][column]);
  }
 }
};

var randomizeMaze = function(){
 var randomX = Math.floor((Math.random() * table.length));
 var randomY = Math.floor((Math.random() * table.length));
 var currentCell = table[randomX][randomY];
 currentCell.isVisited = true;
 adjacencyList.push(currentCell);

 while( adjacencyList.length > 0 ) {

  currentCell.isVisited = true;
  var adjacentNodes = getAdjacentNodes(currentCell);
  //randomly select a node to add to path
  var nextInPath = adjacentNodes[Math.floor((Math.random() * adjacentNodes.length))];
  //add to path to not visit it again
  adjacencyList.push.apply(adjacencyList, adjacentNodes);
  var removeNode = adjacencyList.indexOf(currentCell);
  adjacencyList.splice(removeNode, 1);

  //reset currentCell to random cell from resized list
  currentCell = adjacencyList[Math.floor((Math.random() * adjacencyList.lenth))];
 }
};

function getAdjacentNodes(pCell){
 
 var adjacentNodes = new Array();
 //check left
 if(pCell.x - 1 >= 0){
  var node = table[pCell.x-1][pCell.y];
  adjacentNodes.push(node);
  adjacencyList.push(node);
 }
 //check right
 if(pCell.x + 1 < table.length){
  var node = table[pCell.x+1][pCell.y];
  adjacentNodes.push(node);
  adjacencyList.push(node);
 }
 //check top
 if(pCell.y - 1 >= 0){
  var node = table[pCell.x][pCell.y - 1];
  adjacentNodes.push(node);
  adjacencyList.push(node);
 }

 //check bottom
 if(pCell.y + 1 < table.length){
  var node = table[pCell.x][pCell.y + 1];
  adjacentNodes.push(node);
  adjacencyList.push(node);
 }
 return adjacentNodes;
};

createTable(3);
//print();
randomizeMaze();
```

Whenever I try and access/change any property inside of a cell, namely in the functions 'randomeMaze' and 'getAdjacentNodes', it will throw the error I mentioned. I can print the objects to console, I see the objects as being populated when I debug. Maybe I'm missing something and am going crazy.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One thing I spot is `adjacencyList.lenth` which I presume to mean `length`, but that doesn't match the error you have.  try running your code through http://www.jshint.com/ and see if anything jumps out.

Comment: For some strange reason, that was it. I was so lost as to why it was giving me that error; thanks for pointing that out !